# Matlab installation (LD_LIBRARY_PATH) messes up other library files

Tags: java, python, linux, matlab, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install Matlab on a Linux machine, but setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH (as the installation requires) breaks other library files. I am not an Linux expert, but I have tried several things and cannot get it working correctly. I have even contacted Matlab support, got the issue elevated to the dev team, and was basically told "haha sucks to suck". I have seen a few other people online have had the same issue, but either their questions were never answered or they had a slightly different problem and their solution didn't apply to me.

**Installing on a VM running Ubuntu:**

I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH as the instructions say, then it breaks network files. I can ping google.com, but I cannot nslookup google.com or visit it in a browser. Nslookup provides this error:

```
nslookup: /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v90/bin/glnxa64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/libdns.so.100)
03-Feb-2016 11:32:22.361 ENGINE_by_id failed (crypto failure)
03-Feb-2016 11:32:22.362 error:25070067:DSO support routines:DSO_load:could not load the shared library:dso_lib.c:244:
03-Feb-2016 11:32:22.363 error:260B6084:engine routines:DYNAMIC_LOAD:dso not found:eng_dyn.c:447:
03-Feb-2016 11:32:22.363 error:2606A074:engine routines:ENGINE_by_id:no such engine:eng_list.c:418:id=gost
(null): dst_lib_init: crypto failure
```

The installation worked though (I can run my Java programs that reference compiled Matlab functions). Unsetting LD_LIBRARY_PATH fixes the network files but then I can't run programs anymore.

**Installing on EC2 instance:**

On an EC2 instance it does not break the network files (nslookup is fine). Instead it messes up Python library files. Trying to use any aws cli command, I get the error:

```
File "/usr/bin/aws", line 19, in <module>
  import awscli.clidriver
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 16, in <module>
  import botocore.session
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/session.py", line 25, in <module>
  import botocore.config
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/config.py", line 18, in <module>
  from botocore.compat import six
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/compat.py", line 139, in <module>
  import xml.etree.cElementTree
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/etree/cElementTree.py", line 3, in <module>
  from _elementtree import *
ImportError: PyCapsule_Import could not import module "pyexpat"
```

Printing sys.path in Python shows lib-dynload is already there though, so it doesn't seem to the problem.

And when trying to run the program, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.LinkageError: libXt.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.DynamicLibraryUtils.dlopen(Native Method)
at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.DynamicLibraryUtils.loadLibraryAndBindNativeMethods(DynamicLibraryUtils.java:134)
at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR.<clinit>(MWMCR.java:1529)
at VectorAddExample.VectorAddExampleMCRFactory.newInstance(VectorAddExampleMCRFactory.java:48)
at VectorAddExample.VectorAddExampleMCRFactory.newInstance(VectorAddExampleMCRFactory.java:59)
at VectorAddExample.VectorAddClass.<init>(VectorAddClass.java:62)
at com.mypackage.Example.main(Example.java:13)
```

I'm at a brick wall and really have no clue how to proceed.

Comment: how are you setting the ld_library_path?

Comment: I've used `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v90/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v90/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v90/sys/os/glnxa64:` both manually and in .bashrc

Comment: using export in that manner removes the previous entries in ld_library_path, check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something else already needs LD_LIBRARY_PATH set to work. Make sure you prepend not overwrite:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=new/path:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

**Edit**:

OK, if LD_LIBRARY_PATH was initially empty, this suggests that Matlab comes with shared libraries that are incompatible with your system ones:

```
nslookup: /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v90/bin/glnxa64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/libdns.so.100)
```

suggests that `/usr/lib/libdns.so.100` needs `libcrypto.so.1.0.0`, which is now being resolved to the one that comes with MATLAB, which is incompatible.

You can check the dependencies of a dll by

```
ldd /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

and hopefully you can find a configuration that keeps both MATLAB and your system happy. Unfortunately, this may involve a lot of trial and error.

If there is no such configuration, you can try setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH only when you run MATLAB:

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$MATLAB_LD_LIBRARY_PATH matlab

**Edit 2**:

Well, for the Python issue, it seems to boil down to `pyexpat`, which is a wrapper around the standard `expat` XML parser. Try doing (name guessed since I don't have a Linux right now):

ldd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libpyexpat.so

and see what that depends on. Probably, it will be `libexpat.so`, which is now being resolved to MATLAB's version.

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH is empty before setting it, so it is not overwriting anything.

Comment: I'm amazed the Mathworks can allow their libraries to conflict with peoples' libraries like that and not care about helping to solve it. It's not like Ubuntu 14.04 is some rare, unused OS. Anyway, I assume the `libXt.so.6` error can be solved in a similar fashion. Do you know how I might figure out the Python problem since the Python sys path seems to be correct?

Answer (score 0):

try the following command:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v90/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v90/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v90/sys/os‌​/glnxa64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH is empty before setting it, so it is not overwriting anything.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not helpful for OP but if you are generating a python package with MATLAB, you could modify the generated `__init__.py` file MATLAB creates for your package.

Specifically, the generated `__init__.py` file contains the following line (as of MATLAB 2017a):

```
PLATFORM_DICT = {'Windows': ['PATH','dll',''], 'Linux': ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH','so','libmw'], 'Darwin': ['DYMCR_LIBRARY_PATH','dylib','libmw']}
```

For Linux platform, you could simply replace `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with something else such as `MCR_LIBRARY_PATH` to prevent mucking with your shared libs.

```
sed -i -e 's/LD_LIBRARY_PATH/MCR_LIBRARY_PATH/g' /MY/PACKAGE/BUILD/PATH/__init__.py
```

Then obviously export `MCR_LIBRARY_PATH` before using python.